# Chosen container not showing elements

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

Does anyone know any css property for make the second image look like the first image?

Both dropdown have the same elements but as you see the second doesn't show the elements.
[image]

[image]

**Update:**
I've just changed my css, overflow from hidden to overlay

```
.wizard > .content
{
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    min-height: 120px;
    overflow: overlay;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information including a code sample of the code in question.

Comment: I guess container of whole form has overflow: hidden; so dropdown is hidden of viewport and it goes "under" visible canvas

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński Changing the overflow has worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @LuisRosales no problem, dude :)

Comment: overflow:overlay; it's an invalid property, just comment the overlay setting and you'll get the same result, the browsers just ignore overflow:overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps share some code?

I would inspect the height or max-height of the dropdown. Maybe overflow: hidden is hiding the list. Or if there are floated elements in the list for some reason you might have to put overflow: hidden on the container element to contain the floated elements i.e. expand with the size of it's contents

Comment: Overflow hidden was hiding my list, i have fixed the problem changing to overlay